# Multiple numpy arrays to bytes

Tags: python, numpy

Input/Output:

```
[array([[  2.120417 , -13.725279 ],
       [  2.066555 , -13.953174 ]], dtype=float32)
array([[  1.952603,   6.800025],
       [  1.952603,   6.800025]], dtype=float32)
```

```
b"\x40\x07\xb4\xea\xc1\x5b\x9a\xbe\x3f\xf9\xee\xe5\x40\xd9\x99\xce\x40\x04\x42\x70\xc1\x5f\x40\x33\x3f\xf9\xee\xe5\x40\xd9\x99\xce"
```

Each array contains multiple x, y coordinates (floats). I want to go through one element in an array (one element contains a set of x, y coords) and then the next array at the same index, then after all arrays have been gone through the first index, then the next.

Comment: I would suggest adding more details to your question

Comment: What details am I missing?

Comment: An input/output example for instance

Comment: You might consider whether your life would be easier if you CREATED the data that way.  numpy indexing makes that pretty easy.  Any time you're working with a set of variables like `arr1`, `arr2`, `arr3` etc., you should be thinking "there's a better way to organize this".

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, you can `hstack` and `ravel`:

```
np.hstack([arr1, arr2, arr3]).ravel()
```

Output:

```
array([ 0,  1,  4,  5,  8,  9,  2,  3,  6,  7, 10, 11])
```

Used input (`[arr1, arr2, arr3]`):

```
[array([[0, 1],
        [2, 3]]),
 array([[4, 5],
        [6, 7]]),
 array([[ 8,  9],
        [10, 11]])]
```

Comment: It says: ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 111 and the array at index 1 has size 36. They all have the same horizontal dimension, but they all have difference vertical positions.

Comment: Then can't you slice to the minimal common length? Or is all the data required (in which case this is not detailed in the question)?